# full width header when overflow content (body)

Tags: html, css, css-position

html code:

```
<body>
   <header style="background-color:green;">header</header>
   <main>
      <p>some content</p>
      <div style="width:2000px">some wide content, makes overflow body</div>
      <p>some content</p>
   </main>
   <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

When some content in body is wider than window then vertical scroll appears - this is what I want to have.
But the header and footer has width = 100% of window.

I want to expand header/footer width to content width.
Or (even better solution) header/footer stay with width 100%, I see vertical scroll (on window), but when I start to scroll vertically I will scroll only body. The footer/header stay "sticky".
I cannot use position:fixed, because during horizontally scrolling the header/footer should "move" with content.

Comment: I don't quite understand, an element with its position `fixed` would move with the content when scrolling, vertically or horizontally. You could post a code snippet with your question to demonstrate what you mean, could convey the message a little clearer.

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  /* Take width and height of content and use flexbox layout */
  /* By default all flex items will stretch for cross axis */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* Align all blocks in columns */
  /* All items will stretch in width */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Minimum occupy 100% of screen width */
  min-width: 100vw;
  /* Minimum occupy 100% of screen height */
  /* To get rid of horizontal scrollbar can be changed to smaller value */
  /* e.g. min-height: calc(100vh - 20px) */
  /* Replace min-height with height to also work in IE */
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
 /* Emulating long content */
  width: 9999px;
  /* Take all height */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/* Styles just for demo */
header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class="content">Very long content</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

If you need to make `header` and `footer` fixed only for horizontal direction you can achieve this via JavaScript:

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header");
var footer = document.querySelector("footer");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  var rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  header.style.marginLeft = -rect.left + "px";
  footer.style.marginLeft = -rect.left + "px";
});
```

```css
body {
  /* Take width and height of content and use flexbox layout */
  /* By default all flex items will stretch for cross axis */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* Align all blocks in columns */
  /* All items will stretch in width */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Minimum occupy 100% of screen width */
  min-width: 100vw;
  /* Minimum occupy 100% of screen height */
  /* To get rid of horizontal scrollbar can be changed to smaller value */
  /* e.g. min-height: calc(100vh - 20px) */
  /* Replace min-height with height to also work in IE */
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  /* Emulating long content */
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1000px;
  /* Take all height */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


/* Styles just for demo */

header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class="content">Very long content</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Do you have idea how to stick header/footer to left edge during vertical scrolling?

Comment: Only with JavaScript. As far I understood horizontal and vertical scroll should remain on window.